# only one function is working: cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have two functions which should run after choosing one of the options. The function `setOne()` is somehow not working but the function `myFunction()` is working. I looked at the console and it says:

```
 index.html:103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property **options** of null
    at setOne
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange
```

Can someone help me that the function `setOne()` is also working?

I would appreciate your work!

Here is my code:

```
    <form name="formcalc">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Please select</label>
                <select class="col-sm-10 form-control" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction();setOne();">
                    <option value="0">CHF 0</option>
                    <option value="75000">CHF 75'000</option>
                    <option value="100000">CHF 100'000</option>
                </select>
                <!-- <div class="col-sm-10">                   
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="txtnum1">
                </div> -->
            </div>
            <fieldset disabled>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Output 1</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n1" name="txtres" value="CHF " readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Output 2</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n2" name="txtres2" value="CHF " readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Here is my js code:

```
    <!--JavaScript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" id="javatest">
        function setOne() {
            const selectOne = document.getElementById("selectOne");
            if (selectOne.options[selectOne.selectedIndex].text == "CHF 75'000")
                document.getElementById("n1").value = "CHF 64.80";
            else if (selectOne.options[selectOne.selectedIndex].text == "CHF 100'000")
                document.getElementById("n1").value = "CHF 104.80";
        }    

        function myFunction() {
            var num3 = 1000000;
            var num5 = $('[name=txtres]').css("color", "green").css("font-weight", "bold").val();
            var num6 = $('[name=txtres2]').css("color", "red").css("font-weight", "bold").val();
            document.formcalc.txtres2.value = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CHF' }).format(num3);

            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div class="output">This is a text';
        }    
    </script>
```

Comment: You don't have element with `id="selectOne"` you have `id="mySelect"`

Comment: There is no dom with id `selectOne` so  `document.getElementById("selectOne");` will fail

Comment: There is no id with selectOne in your html. You are referring to a property of an element which doesnt not exist, and hence throwing the error. Since the myFunction() doesnot have any null reference, it excutes perfectly.

Comment: o man... didn't see that. thx guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element in your HTML code with `id="selectOne"!` You need to change your code

`document.getElementById("selectOne")`

to

```
document.getElementById("mySelect")
```

or you can change your html code with

```
<select class="col-sm-10 form-control" id="mySelect" .......
```

to

```
<select class="col-sm-10 form-control" id="selectOne" ...................
```

Just use same id in both HTML and java script

Answer (score 0):

In `setOne()`, change:

```
document.getElementById("selectOne");
```

as:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect");
```